# PostgreSQL replaces LF with CR+LF in TEXT fields using Python pyodbc

Tags: python, postgresql, text, newline, pyodbc

On MS Windows, using Python 3's `pyodbc` module, I'm working with PostgreSQL. When I use PostgreSQL's `TEXT` data type and attempt to store UNIX-like EOLs, the original `\n` gets replaced with `\r\n`. See the example below.

```
import pyodbc

def main():

    connection = pyodbc.connect(
                   'DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)};'
                   'SERVER=127.0.0.1;'
                   'UID=postgres;'
                   'PWD=topsecret;'
                   'DATABASE=db1');
    cursor = connection.cursor();

    cursor.execute('CREATE SCHEMA schema1 '
                     'CREATE TABLE table1 ('
                       'key SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,'
                       'value TEXT'
                     ')');

    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO schema1.table1 (value) VALUES (?)',
                   'hello\nworld');

    r = cursor.execute('SELECT value FROM schema1.table1').fetchone()[0];

    print(r == 'hello\nworld');    # prints False

    print(r == 'hello\r\nworld');  # prints True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main();
```

Indeed, such behavior might be advantageous in some cases. However, in my case, it's undesirable. I was unable to find how to turn off this feature in PostgreSQL's docs, and am not actually sure where exactly the replacement takes place. Any ideas?

Comment: Why use `pyodbc` not the rather superior `psycopg2`?

Comment: Also, I'd say the transformation is probably within the ODBC driver. Check the DSN settings pages.

Comment: @CraigRinger You're right, I just tried ``psycopg2`` instead of ``pyodbc`` and the LF → CR+LF does not take place anymore. It'll really be within the driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's a behaviour of the ODBC driver its self, not the Python interface to it. That said, you're almost certainly better off using `psycopg2`, which will be simpler, more powerful and faster.

Just like `psqlODBC`, `psycopg2` wraps `libpq` but it does so without the clunky ODBC mid-layer.

Comment: I just posted a screenshot of a configuration window I've discovered based on your advice. However, you're right that ``pyodbc`` was probably and odd choice. I'll refactor my code and switch to ``psycopg2``, though my code is 30 kB in size :-(

Comment: Great! I did some regexp/manual refactoring and completely switched to ``psycopg2``. All the unit tests seem to work just fine now :-)

Comment: @Tregoreg Glad to hear you got it going, and thanks for following up with the exact config option for it in psqlODBC. I'm using Fedora 18 not Windows so it was kind of hard for me to look for it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @CraigRinger's hint, I've been able to add new DSN, `PostgreSQL35W`, using `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe`. The configuration allows us to turn off the LF ↔ CR/LF conversion as shown on the below screenshot:

[image: Options page for PostgreSQL DNS]

Using `DSN=PostgreSQL35W` instead of `DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)}` fixed the problem.